# Updating entity using model mapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have a strange problem with model mapper. Probably I missunderstand how it works.
What I have: an example Model class:

```
class Model{
 String name;
 String surname;
 Integer age;
 ...and much much more
```

And a method

```
private void foo(){
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        Model model = Model.builder().name("foo").surname("bar").age(23).build();
        Model newModel = Model.builder().name("john").build();
        modelMapper.map(newModel, model);
        System.out.println(model.toString());
}
```

And the output is: `Model(name=john, surname=null, age=null)`
But what I expect `Model(name=john, surname=bar, age=23)`
Can I do this using model mapper? If not, how to do this easily (i dont want update manually each property)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using Lombok builder `@Builder.Default` You just need to update your Model class

```
public class Model {
    @Builder.Default
    String name = "foo";
    @Builder.Default
    String surname = "bar";
    @Builder.Default
    Integer age = 23;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you misunderstood how it works : it works well in your case. It is mapping null values too. If you do not want that, you can use that code inside a Spring Configuration class dedicated to ModelMapper :

```
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration()
            .setFieldAccessLevel(Configuration.AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
            .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STANDARD)
            .setSkipNullEnabled(true);
    return modelMapper;
}
```

The important part is `setSkipNullEnabled(true)` which handle that globally here. Take care of that when you are handling forms.